# Ubuntu 14.04 Install opencv3.0, meet relocation error

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

Here is my make log:

```
[  3%] Built target libwebp
[  3%] Built target opencv_cudev
[  7%] Built target opencv_ts_pch_dephelp
[  7%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ts
[  7%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[  7%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[ 11%] Built target opencv_core
[ 11%] Built target opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[ 11%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgproc
[ 15%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 15%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp
[ 15%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgcodecs
[ 15%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs
[ 15%] Built target opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp
[ 15%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_videoio
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavformat.a(rmsipr.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried to re-build ffmpeg from source, in the beginning, make in ffmpeg meets similiar problem but after I configure using this command:

```
./configure --prefix=.. --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-outdev=sdl --disable-opencl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --cc="gcc -m64 -fPIC" --extra-cflags="-I../include" --extra-ldflags="-L../lib -ldl"
```

the ffmpeg is built.

But the opencv make error is still there..

Searched a lot and cannot find a solution.

Comment: solved: remake x264 and ffmpeg with --enable-shared flag during configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remake x264 and ffmpeg basically according to this post:http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation-2-3-1/ (remember to add --enable-shared when configuring x264 and ffmpeg) will solve this problem.

Comment: This solution don't work if Ubuntu's supplied libav libararies are used. Which makes me wonder why, as the supplied libraries are shared by default.